Kong API Gateway - docker container on windows, fail to bind - port in use after laptop reboot
Each time I reboot my laptop, Kong API Gateway fails to bind and start.
If I delete and recreate it's all fine, just the reboots mean recreating each time and reperforming setup.
I am using Kong gateway on docker with these commands,
Create a Docker Network (this step is not needed if using host network mode):
docker network create kong-net

Run the PostgreSQL Database Container:
docker run -d --name kong-database --net=host -e POSTGRES_USER=kong -e POSTGRES_DB=kong -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong postgres:latest

Run the Kong Gateway Container and Bootstrap Migrations:
docker run --rm --net=host -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" -e "KONG_PG_HOST=localhost" -e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" -e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kongpass" kong:latest kong migrations bootstrap

Start the Kong Gateway Container:
docker run -d --name kong --net=host -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" -e "KONG_PG_HOST=localhost" -e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" -e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kongpass" -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" -e "KONG_ADMIN_GUI_URL=http://localhost:8002" -p 8000:8000 -p 8443:8443 -p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001 -p 127.0.0.1:8002:8002 -p 127.0.0.1:8444:8444 kong:latest

so the above works fine and I can connect to kong locally on http://localhost:8002
then I perform a reboot of my laptop and I get the error belwo and need to redo the installation again...  this is so annoying...
Please help....your guidance is appreciated!!!
--- startup error after reboot is :  these logs are from the kong container where it fails
2024-10-07 05:39:51 nginx: [emerg] bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:51 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [notice] 1#0: try again to bind() after 500ms
2024-10-07 05:39:51 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [emerg] 1#0: bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:51 nginx: [emerg] bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:51 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [notice] 1#0: try again to bind() after 500ms
2024-10-07 05:39:52 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [emerg] 1#0: bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:52 nginx: [emerg] bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:52 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [notice] 1#0: try again to bind() after 500ms
2024-10-07 05:39:52 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [emerg] 1#0: bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:52 nginx: [emerg] bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:52 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [notice] 1#0: try again to bind() after 500ms
2024-10-07 05:35:26 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2024:04:35:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16463 "http://localhost:8002/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/129.0.0.0"
2024-10-07 05:39:53 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [emerg] 1#0: bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:53 nginx: [emerg] bind() to unix:/usr/local/kong/sockets/we failed (98: Address already in use)
2024-10-07 05:39:53 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [notice] 1#0: try again to bind() after 500ms
2024-10-07 05:39:53 2024/10/07 04:39:48 [emerg] 1#0: still could not bind()
2024-10-07 05:39:53 nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()

note:
I am running my laptop with a bridge to support Hyper-V cluster
I have turned on --net=host support in docker network too.
set --net=host and fresh installs

--net=host isn't usually the setup you want, since it disables most Docker networking features.  Can you use --net=kong-net instead?  You already have the docker run -p options you need.

I got the answer from another person:

he asked me to stop the containers before doing the reboots.

Thats it...that solved the issue...
The containers were getting corrupted by just executing a reboot on my laptop.
I tested the process multiple times, and the gateway container got corrupted if I just rebooted without stopping the container first.
Knowing to stop the containers first would have saved me many hours of digging into a problem that did not exist!
I hope you stop your containers first too.  Maybe even exit the docker desktop so it stops all the containers before rebooting.
